# Why does nuxt3 getCookie() give different results based on where the route is called from?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a simple route in `server/api/verify.js`

```js
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  let error = null
  const token = getCookie(event, 'jwt')

  if (token) {
    await jsonwebtoken.verify(token, 'someSecret', (err) => {
      if (err) { error = err.message }
    })
  } else {
    return { error: 'no token' }
  }

  return error ? { error } : { ok: true }
})
```

and if I test the route in the browser, it gives the expected results,
but when I try to use it in a component or in a middleware function with:

```js
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/verify')
```

then it always results in `no token` error. The token is undefined.   What am I missing?